# react-player resizing itself until it fits container

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a component using react-player to display a video. Here is the react

```js
const playerComponent = (
    <div
      className={`relative h-35dvh aspect-video flex justify-center items-center rounded-lg overflow-hidden`}
    >
      <ReactPlayer
        playsInline={true}
        height="100%"
        width="100%"
        playing={true}
        controls
        url={currentMediaURL}
      />
    </div>
);
```

For some reason, when the video loads, it loads really small, and then it resizes twice before fitting the size of its parent container. Can anyone help me figure out how to ensure the video always loads with 100% width and height of its parent?